# Where can I find a map of US county boundaries that reasonably shows the boundaries over bodies of water?

Tags: data-request, usa, county

Census, ESRI, and others provide shapefiles and feature classes of county boundaries, but all the data sets I can find seem to clip the boundaries at the shoreline. So they really only show the boundaries over land, but not over water, that is, bodies of water along a boundary are shown to not be in any county.

I need a similar data source that shows the boundaries between counties over both land and water. Great accuracy is not needed, I just need data that resemble the typical printed map where there is one relatively smooth boundary between adjacent counties (for example) following the course of a river, instead of two boundaries along the two shorelines.

I would have assumed that Census and others start with maps with the boundaries in the water, but my search skills have not been good enough to find such sources.

Any idea where I might find such a data set?

Comment: I would suggest to have a look on OSM data. Example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/37.7772/-76.6783 - you can see a crossing of boundaries on the water. You can get the data from https://download.geofabrik.de.

Comment: @Grzegorz Sapijaszko: Thanks.  You are correct that this source has what I am seeking.

Comment: Welcome, @Jim Titus. Let me know, if you need a help with processing the data. Boundaries in OSM are described with `boundary = administrative` and `admin_level = ...` keys/values. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative for details